# nlme() convergence error code = 1

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I was trying to use the nlme package in r to do a multilevel linear model.

I have yield as response variable and rainfall as predictor variable for 60 years for 6 different locations (State). I am trying to see whether rainfall has same level of effect on yield in all locations or different effects. In principle, I am trying to see if slope of yield vs rainfall significantly varies between locations. Therefore rainfall is my random effect. I built my model like this:

```
 # baseline model which only includes intercept
mdl1<-gls(yield ~ 1,data = data, method="ML")

#intercept as random effect
mdl2<-lme(yield ~ 1,data=data,random = ~1|state,method="ML")  

 # slope as random effect
mdl3<-lme(yield ~ rain, data = data, random = ~rain|state,method="ML")

##compare the three model
anova(mdl1,mdl2,mdl3)
##this shows me when I add slope as random effect, my model shows better fit compared to baseline model (mdl1)
```

this is all working fine. The problem starts when I do the same analysis using an another predictor variable (a count data)

```
 # baseline model which only includes intercept: Works fine
mdl4<-gls(yield ~ 1,data = data, method="ML")

#intercept as random effect - works fine
mdl5<-lme(yield ~ 1,data=data,random = ~1|state,method="ML")  

 # include different predictor (break) this time instead of rain
mdl6<-lme(yield ~ break, data = data, random = ~break|state,method="ML")
```

when i run the mdl 6, this gives me the error

```
Error in lme.formula(res_yld ~ brk, data = data, random = ~brk | state,  : 
nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)
```

I have absolutely no clue why is this happening. Everything worked fine for my first predictor but this does not work on another predictor. What am I doing wrong here? I tried reading about this online but the posts are not very clear to me. I would really appreciate of anyone could me out on this.
Thanks

Comment: How many values of break do you have within each state, i.e., the cross table of break and state w.r.t yield?

Comment: my break data for each State is 48 i.e. i have 48 years of yield data (48 observations of yield) and 48 years of break days (48 observations for break days) for each State. and i am trying to see whether the relationship between yield and break days is similar or different across the States.

Comment: How many different values of yield for each combination of break and state? As your error-code shows, nlme is using the nlminb-procedure. I've experienced strange behaviour of that procedure which for instance shows values for the target function for estimates which can in fact not be evaluated. I would recommend using optim if no bounds are specified and to reduce the number of break and state combination say in half, run nlme, if no problem occurs then increase until error occurs. Then look at the data. This trail and error ususally finds the error quite quickly.

Comment: Another idea is to supply starting values for the optimization. Your process might converge if it started closer to the actual parameter values rather than starting from a random location.

Answer (score 4):

It probably has something to do with the number of levels of Break, which makes the model to be overparametrized. You should increase the maximum number of iterations for nlminb, see `nlmeControl()`, the defaul value is 50, then try with higer values:

```
mdl6<-lme(yield ~ break, data = data, random = ~break|state,method="ML", control=(msMaxIter=100))
```

Comment: Increasing iterations didn't work for me but this solution did: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/lme-error-iteration-limit-reached