# What am I modeling with R vs. SPSS mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, spss

I am trying to model a 3-way repeated measures experiment, FixedFactorA * FixedFactorB * Time[days]. There are no missing observations, but my groups (FactorA * FactorB) are unequal (close, but not completely balanced). From reading online, the best way to model a repeated measures experiment in which observation order matters (due to the response mean and variance changing in a time-dependent way) and for unequal groups is to use a mixed model and specify an appropriate covariance structure.  **However, I am new to the idea of mixed models and I am confused as to whether I am using the correct syntax to model what I am trying to model.**

I would like to do a full factorial analysis, such that I could detect significant time * factor interactions.  For example, for subjects with FactorA = 1, their responses over time might have a different slope and/or intercept than subjects with FactorA =2.  I also want to be able to check whether certain combinations of FactorA and FactorB have significantly different responses over time (hence the full three-way interaction term).

From reading online, it seems like AR1 is a reasonable covariance structure for longitudinal-like data, so I decided to try that.  Also, I saw that one is supposed to use ML if one plans to compare two different models, so I chose that approach in anticipation of needing to fine-tune the model.  It is also my understanding that the goal is to minimize the AIC during model selection.

This is the code in the log for what I tried in SPSS (for long-form data), which yielded an AIC of 2471:

```
MIXED RESPONSE BY FactorA FactorB Day
  /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0,
ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
  /FIXED=FactorA FactorB Day FactorA*FactorB FactorA*Day FactorB*Day FactorA*FactorB*Day | SSTYPE(3)
  /METHOD=ML
  /PRINT=SOLUTION TESTCOV
  /REPEATED=Day | SUBJECT(Subject_ID) COVTYPE(AR1)
```

This is what I tried in R, which yielded an AIC of 2156:

```
    require(nlme)

    #output error fix: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/lme-error-iteration-limit-reached

    ctrl <- lmeControl(opt='optim')

    fit1 <- lme(RESPONSE ~ Day*FactorA*FactorB, random = ~ Day|Subject_ID, control=ctrl,
        correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data, method="ML")

    summary(fit1)
```

These are my questions:

1. The SPSS code above yielded a model with AIC = 2471, while the R code yielded a model with AIC = 2156.  What is it about the codes that makes the models different?
2. From what I described above, are either of these models appropriate for what I am trying to test? If not, what would be a better way, and how would I do it in both programs to get the same results?
3. What is the appropriate way to compare models in both R and SPSS, such that the comparison tests are the same regardless of the software being used? For example, how do you do something like anova.lme() in SPSS?

***Edits***

Another thing to note is that I didn't dummy-code my factors.  I don't know if this is a problem for either software, or if the built-in coding is different in SPSS vs R.  I also don't know if this will be a problem for my three-way interaction term.

Also, when I say "factor", I mean an unchanging group or characteristic (like "sex").

Comment: Check the final model coefficients. Are they the same in SPSS as in R?

Comment: _"What is it about the codes that makes the models different?"_: a programming question, but AIC includes a term which is constant across models; many ommit this term.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about model coefficients (as nothing is labeled as such in the output), but the fixed-effects "values" column in the R output and the estimates of fixed effects "estimates" column in the SPSS output do not match

Comment: You cannot compare AIC between different software unless you know exactly what formula they both use. Even then it is best used to compare models within software.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, CrossValidated is not for programming questions. That would be Stack Overflow, but it looks like your SPSS syntax does not include a random component nor have you specified a covariance structure, which would yield different AIC values.

For longitudinal analysis using multi-level modelling (also called hierarchical level modelling), you first should create an"unconditional model," such that

$Level 1:$

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1(time_{j})+e_{j}$

$Level 2:$

$\beta_0=\gamma_{00}+U_0$

$\beta_1=\gamma_{10}+U_1$

Where $Var(e_{j})=\sigma^2$, $Var(U_0)=\tau_{00})$, $Var(U_1)=\tau_{11}$, and $Cov(U_1,U_2)=\tau_{01}$, or in matrix notation:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ \tau_{00} & \tau_{01} \\
\ \tau_{10} & \tau_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Now, construct a "conditional model," with a control group ($group_{j2}$)

$Level 1:$

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1(time_{j1})+\beta_2(group_{j2})+e_{j}$

$Level 2:$

$\beta_0=\gamma_{00}+U_0$

$\beta_1=\gamma_{10}+U_1$

$\beta_2=\gamma_{20}+U_2$

Where $Var(e_{j})=\sigma^2$, but the $\tau$ matrix now has an added element, such that:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ \tau_{00} & \tau_{01} &\tau_{02}\\
\ \tau_{10} & \tau_{11} & \tau_{12}\\
\ \tau_{20} & \tau_{21} & \tau_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Further, you can add two time-variant predictors (which you call factors and I notate as $factor_ij$). Thus, observations over $time_j$ are nested in factors, such that:

$Level 1:$

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1(time_{j1})+\beta_2(group_{j2})+e_{ij}$

$Level 2:$

$\beta_0=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{01}(factor_{ij})+U_0$

$\beta_1=\gamma_{10}+\gamma_{11}(factor_{ij})+U_1$

$\beta_2=\gamma_{20}+\gamma_{21}(factor_{ij})+U_2$

Where Where $Var(e_{j})=\sigma^2$, and the $\tau$ matrix is:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ \tau_{00} & \tau_{01} &\tau_{02}\\
\ \tau_{10} & \tau_{11} & \tau_{12}\\
\ \tau_{20} & \tau_{21} & \tau_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Then, repeat each of these models, but where $Var(e_{ij})=AR(1)$, with rows and columns equal to $j$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ 1 & \rho & \dots & \rho^{j-1}\\
\ \rho & 1 & \dots & \rho^{j-2}\\
\ \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
\ \rho^{j-1} & \dots & \dots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Each of these six models yields an AIC. You can compare using a $\chi^2$ difference test, where the AIC is your test statistic and the number of estimated parameters is your $df$.

For more information, see Raudenbush & Bryk (2002).

Comment: I thought that I took care of the subject effect using the "repeated" part; in that part of the spss code, I specified the covariance structure based on the instructions from the help website.   Is this not appropriate?  What is the difference between /REPEATED and /RANDOM?

Comment: Stack Overflow is better suited to continue your question about SPSS syntax. I only use SPSS if absolutely necessary because I pRefeR R. I justknow it doesn't match my template for longitudinal mixed models, but there's more than one way to skin() a print.cat().

Comment: Also, factor A and Factor B are constant.  They do not vary over time.  For example, "Sex" could be one of the factors.

Comment: Ah! If Factor A and Factor B are constant, they would be "time-invariant" and would go on the level-1 of the hierarchical linear model.

Comment: Since you are an R user: how does the R code I had for fit1 compare to the fancy equations in your answer?  `fit1 <- lme(RESPONSE ~ Day*FactorA*FactorB, random = ~ Day|Subject_ID, control=lmeControl(opt='optim'),
        correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data, method="ML")`  Or should I re-ask this question on stackoverflow?

Comment: I recommend Stack Overflow. I do recommend getting a pencil and some paper and finding the "mixed model," which is where you plug in the $\beta$ equations into $Level 1$. There, you'll see that the fixed effects have gamma coefficients and the random effects are distributed on the $U$ terms. I've never used the `control` command in `lme` because I think a grouping variable in level 1 makes more sense.

Comment: While the above is good information, I am not sure the decomposed notation from raudenbush & Bryk will help when using R. lme4 and other packages use coding schemes that translate well into non-decomposed model statements. Decomposes notation does not really help all that much. And for what its worth, I feel that Raudenbush & Bryk (2002)'s technique is great for organizational research but is not nearly as intuitive for longitudinal research. Further, I feel they dont really handle model effect sizes well. But I know that researchers in education seem to love the text. I prefer Faraway (2014).

Comment: I must admit that I am struggling to understand the notation and how it relates to the syntax for R.  Also, I used the control command because otherwise I get an error...I don't really understand what it is.

Comment: I have [re-posted on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722731/r-vs-spss-mixed-model-repeated-measures-code-from-cross-validated) as well